# Ubuntu 12.04 separate x screen Nvidia black dashboard and window decoration

Tags: unity, 12.04, nvidia, compiz

OS: Ubuntu 12.04
Grafic Card: Nvidia GTX 9800+
First Monitor: View Sonic 1920x1080
Second Monitor: Samsung 1280x1024
In NVidia X Server Settings set "Separate X screen" with enable Xinerama
Everything work but dashboard become black(without opacity), in some app(firefox, NVIDIA X server settings, etc.), window decoration become classic, but in nautilus like in settings "Ambiance", when move mouse between monitors in View Sonic mouse start position padding-left 1280px ).  Any idea how to fix or where email?

P.S. NVidia driver version 295.40.

Answer (score 2):

It's a known bug, you should upvote the bug here:

https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/libxinerama/+bug/973419

so it gets more attention.